# OpenLayers vector layers don't render at certain zoom levels in Chrome browser

Tags: openlayers, zoom, vector-layer, rendering, chrome

Environment:

- Chrome browser
- Typescript
- Angular
- OpenLayers 8.0

I have two OpenLayers maps side by side.  They need to be synced in all respects except for one layer. So I'm using the same layers and view in both Maps. The Layers are all VectorLayer<VectorSource>.

- If I load the page at Chrome browser zoom level 100%, 50%, 33% and some others, everything works perfectly.
- If I load the page at Chrome browser zoom level 80%, 90%, **I have one map that renders and the other that displays nothing**.
- If I load the page at a functioning zoom level (example 100%) and then change chrome zoom level to 80 or 90%, everything still works perfectly, so 1) have a very easy work around, 2) I know layers can render at these zoom levels.
- If I load the page at a NON functioning zoom level (example 80%) and then change chrome zoom level to 100% or 50%, the bug is still present (1 layer doesn't display, **sometimes the rendered layers flicker from one map to the next and back**.

The good news:

1. I have a very easy work around,
2. I know layers can render at these zoom levels.

Has anyone run into a similar problem or do you know enough about OpenLayers lifecycle to tell me why in the case that I load the page at ex.: 80%, 90% one of the maps displays nothing?

Comment: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/changelog/upgrade-notes.md#layers-can-only-be-added-to-a-single-map  You can use the same source but it needs to be wrapped in a new layer.